# SortedList does not stay sorted after I change a field

Tags: java, javafx, sortedlist, observablelist

I have an ObservableList filled with Objectives. I don't care what the order of the original list is. I am using a sorted list to handle the sorting.

For this particular list, I am letting the comparator sort according to the Objectives' magnitude level. In the first case, Objective one < two.

Now, if I change the magnitude via the original list or via the Objectives directly, the sortedlist will not sort itself.

If I use the set() method from the sorted list, however, it will sort itself. Is there no other way to set fields and have the sorted list sort itself out?

**I want to make changes to the original list and have the sorted list realize this.**

```
    ObservableList<Objective> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Objective one = new Objective(), two = new Objective();
    one.setMagnitude(10);
    two.setMagnitude(5);
    list.addAll(one, two);
    SortedList<Objective> sorted = new SortedList<Objective>(list,
            (Comparator<? super Objective>) (Objective x, Objective y) -> {
                int first = x.getMagnitude();
                int second = y.getMagnitude();
                if (first > second)
                    return 1;
                else if (second > first)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            });
    System.out.println("SortedList:" + sorted.toString());
    list.get(0).setMagnitude(1);
    list.get(1).setMagnitude(50);
    System.out.println("SortedList:" + sorted.toString());
    System.out.println("Source List:" + list.toString());

SortedList:[5, 10]
SortedList:[50, 1]
Source List:[1, 50]
```

Comment: what would happen if you modified `sorted` not `list`.  Even if you print `list` at the beginning, it would not be sorted.

Comment: Add a listener to the list and trigger sort inside the listener implementation.

Comment: As I said above, using sortedList.set() will actually modify both the source list AND sorted list. The difference is that using the SortedList.set() method will actually correctly sort the sorted list in real time. I would like to achieve the same effect without using that set method. I have also tried triggering FXCollections.sort and sortedList.sort() manually, but they resulted in errors. Let me try them again.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a list sorted all time, would require tracking all object change, which is a big calculation overhead with little to no benefit in most of the tasks.

You should populate your sorted list only after your objects comparison features stable.